# $rootScope:inprog Action already In Progress

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-material

I started to work with `Angular Material` and have a hard time understanding an issue with the `$scope`.`apply` functionality... whenever I try to notify the UI about changes by calling `apply` it fails with an error. I know there are similiar questions on SO, but in my case data is not stored by the `scope` but by the controller instance...

I also use `TypeScript` for my controller implementation; not sure, but this seems to be quite uncommon, since most sample code I found is based on an inline controller implementation right in the view.

My controller looks like that...

```
module MyApp {

    export class MyController {

        private scope: angular.IScope;
        private http: angular.IHttpService;

        public model: { data: SampleData } = { data: { } };

        constructor($scope: angular.IScope, $http: angular.IHttpService) {
            this.scope = $scope;
            this.http = $http;
        }

        public querySampleData(): void {

            const serviceEndpoint: string = "http://localhost:8080/api/";
            var promise: ng.IHttpPromise<SampleData> = this.http.get(serviceEndpoint + "sample", { });

            var callback: ng.IHttpPromiseCallback<SampleData> = (
                data: SampleData,
                status: number,
                headers: angular.IHttpHeaderGetter,
                config: angular.IRequestConfig) => {
                this.scope.apply(() => {
                    this.model.data = data;
                };
            };

            promise.success(callback);
        }
    }

    export interface SampleData {
        message? string;
    }
}
```

The controller provides the `querySampleData` method which obtains some data from a remote service (it uses `IHttpService` for asynchronous API calls). The controller is utilized by the view in the following way...

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <body ng-controller="MyController as c">
        <div>
            <button ng-click="c.querySampleData()" 
                    aria-label="Query sample data">Query sample data</button>
            <p>{{c.model.data.message}}</p>
        </div>
        ...
        <script src="../scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = angular.module("app", ["ngMaterial"]);
            app.controller("MyController", [ "$scope", "$http", MyApp.MyController ]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The initialization of the controller works fine; all dependencies get properly injected into the controller and also the binding to the `querySampleData` method works as expected (when I click the button the method is called). If I assign the received data to the model the UI is not updated, so I added a call to the `$apply` method in order to inform the UI about changes... which gives me the error I mentioned above.

**Update:**

The documentation at: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog recommends to use `$timeout` instead of `$apply` to ensure asynchronous execution; of course this fixes the error, but the UI does not change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS promises already call `.apply()` (under the hood) on their callbacks. You cannot call `.apply` again inside the callbacks since they're already being .applied, and the error "In Progress" tells exactly that. Just remove the `.apply` call and it will work, unless you have further errors.

Comment: Okay; I figured out why I did not see any changes in the UI... it was because I used the alias `c` out of its scope... stupid me (-; Your answer is correct; if the binding is fine there´s no need to manually call `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try 
`this.model.data = data;` and then `this.scope.apply();`